# Problem importing .xlsx local data in Google Colab (for use with pandas)

Tags: dropbox, xlsx, google-colaboratory

1) I tried importing data from a file on my computer (MacBook) in Google Colab (viChrome)

```
import pandas
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pandas.read_excel(open('/Users/ME/Documents/WIP/XL2PDtest.xlsx','rb'), sheet_name=2)

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
```

and got the answer

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ME/Documents/WIP/XL2PDtest.xlsx'
```

What went wrong ?

2) Side question to the members who will help me : may I use your solution if I search for a file in Dropbox ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

try

```py
from google.colab import files
import pandas
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

uploaded = files.upload()
filename = list(uploaded.keys())[0]
df = pandas.read_excel(open(filename 'rb'), sheet_name=2)

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
```

when you run it, you can upload file

```
files.upload()
```

is method to upload file
look for example https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=vz-jH8T_Uk2c

for dropbox read more here https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have problems : 1) Colab asks me to select a file (I thought it would be selected automatically) 2) the upload is horribly slow 3) I get the error "IndexError: list index out of range".(for the line "filename = list(uploaded.keys())[0]")  ; did I make a mistake ? Thanks again

Comment: 1) then store your file in Google Drive (support by Colab) or Dropbox (via dropbox  python sdk) and access it.

2) store file in Dropbox and Google Drive instead to upload is a faster way.

3) might be uploading file failed cause this error?